# A React component re-renders when its parent re-renders and props changes, but how can props change without parent re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs

It is said that a React component re-renders when:

1. Its state changes
2. Its props change
3. Its parent re-renders
4. The context changes

But I don't quite understand, doesn't (3) already cover (2)?  How can the props change without the parent component re-rendering?

Comment: Perhaps the parent component could re-render for its own state change, unrelated to the props being passed to this component?  I imagine the two cases are explicitly outlined just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't quite understand, isn't (3) already cover (2)?

This is just one case and for the most part you will only use it that way. It is also one of the best practices.
However, there are ways to `re-render` the `child component` without `trigger re-rendering` the `parent component` by changing `props`.

Quick reminder:

> React components only re-render when their `render function` is called.

For example when using a `setter function` or changing `props`. Each one of the two cause the `render function` to be called.

Examples for your question:

1. If the `props` comes from an `API`. When The `API` changes `props`, the `child component` will `re-render` without `re-rendering` the `parent component`.
2. The `props` are passed to the `child component` as a `function`, and the `function` is called to get `props`, then the `child component` will `re-render` even if the `parent component` does not.

To conclude, props can be changed without the `re-rendering` of `parent component`.

Comment: oh you are talking about the class components. What about the functional components?

Comment: It's for both. I updated the answer, I hope it's more clear know. I will try to clearify it more if other ideas come to my mind.